# Search everywhere in intellij stoped working

Tags: intellij-idea

When I search everywhere in intellij I get only the latest files I worked on and not the full results.

Is there any way to fix this besides re-install ?

Comment: invalidate caches, reinstall won't do anything.

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart, also check the gear icon which filters the results of the Search Everywhere.

Comment: same problem with my installation - most of the time the search is not working reliably. did you find a workaround / fix for this problem yet? this is a really annoying issue!

Answer (score -1):

try using Ctrl+shift+R?
this acts like search everywhere and allows you to replace words too

Comment: Using Ctrl+Shift+F for searching but ctrl+shift+R retunrs the same .

Comment: using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5
Build #IU-172.4343.14, built on September 26, 2017

Comment: He meant Main menu | Navigate | File..., by default ctrl+shift+N, with Eclipse keymap ctrl+shift+R